# Visual Studio 2013 unable to create new wpf application

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013

Previously i was able to create a new Wpf application from my Visual Studio 2013 Professional.
But recently whenever i tried to create a new Wpf application it will just hang.

I tried uninstalling VS and then reinstalling it
but the same problem persists

Comment: Do you have some more information? e.g. does the output window provide any information?

Comment: ok after uninstall and reinstall it finally works.... able to create a new wpf project but it was really slow....